# gem install trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a weird trouble, i've updated the .irbrc file to make better looking, for this I
installed awesome_print, wirble and looksee gems, check them by gem list - every gem is there.
And when i run rails console i got this:

```
Cannot find awesome_print gem. Please run 'gem install awesome_print' to install it.
Cannot find wirble. Please run 'gem install wirble' to install it.
Cannot find looksee. Please run 'gem install looksee' to install it.
```

I've no idea why it happen. I have rvm on my system but I don't think it causes the problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install gems in Rails 3, add them to your `Gemfile`

For instance:

```
gem 'awesome_print'
gem 'wirble'
gem 'looksee'
```

Then run `bundle install`.

It's also a best practice to create a gemset with `rvm` per-project to isolate dependencies among projects.

To do this, in your Rails root directory run: `rvm --create --rvmrc 1.9.2@myproject` (substitute 1.9.2 with whatever version of Ruby you want to use).

After creating the gemset, rerun `bundle install`.

You'll notice an `.rvmrc` file has been created, which makes sure whenever you `cd` to that directory, the "myproject" gemset will automatically be used.  Add this to version control so other developers get the same effect.

Comment: If you are using bundler you don't need to use a gemset for each project you have. Bundler makes sure that gems you don't have in your `Gemfile` cannot be used.

Comment: It works, but i can't understand why, the gemfile belongs to project and i working with ruby environment (changing .irbrc file), in my opinion these things are different.